# How to use service workers in Quasar Framework (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, quasar-framework

So i am building a mobile PWA built with capacitor for Android and iOS and i want to integrate a service worker to handle incoming push notifications from firebase while the app is closed. I followed [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive) firebase tutorial so far, but i am already really really confused where to start... maybe this is because i am pretty new to PWA's and completely new to service workers, i don't know.

I am using the Quasar framework with Vue.js 2. My folder structure looks like this:

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ebjZ.png)

my "regster-service-worker.js" was initialized by quasar as this:

```
import { register } from 'register-service-worker'

// The ready(), registered(), cached(), updatefound() and updated()
// events passes a ServiceWorkerRegistration instance in their arguments.
// ServiceWorkerRegistration: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration

register(process.env.SERVICE_WORKER_FILE, {
  // The registrationOptions object will be passed as the second argument
  // to ServiceWorkerContainer.register()
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/register#Parameter

  // registrationOptions: { scope: './' },

  ready (/* registration */) {
    console.log('Service worker is active.')
  },

  registered (/* registration */) {
    console.log('Service worker has been registered.')
  },

  cached (/* registration */) {
    console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.')
  },

  updatefound (/* registration */) {
    console.log('New content is downloading.')
  },

  updated (/* registration */) {
    console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')
  },

  offline () {
    console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.')
  },

  error (/* err */) {
    console.error('Error during service worker registration:', err)
  }
})
```

So as i said, i really don't know where to start here. I looked up the mozilla documentation, which provides me a way different approach to this as i have seen elsewhere, like in the tutorial linked above. And before i start coding random things together again and wasting a lot of time tomorrow at work, i rather ask you guys here today and hope for helpful answers from you.

If you need any additional info just post a comment. Thanks in advance! :))

Comment: Why are you staying on VueJS2 instead of version 3 ?